# Tailwind UI Toggle with Checkbox Alpine JS

Tags: html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I've got the tailwind UI toggle working. However the toggle it self doesn't do anything in a form. It needs a Checkbox. Hence I'm trying to add a checkbox that checks and unchecks when the toggle is clicked.

I gave it the right data-model, but nothing happens.

```
<div>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-between" x-data="{ on: false }">
    <span class="flex flex-grow flex-col">
      <span class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900" id="availability-label">Books</span>
      <span class="text-sm text-gray-500" id="availability-description">Yes gibe me a free book</span>
    </span>
    <button type="button"
      class="relative inline-flex h-6 w-11 flex-shrink-0 cursor-pointer rounded-full border-2 border-transparent transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:ring-offset-2 bg-gray-200"
      role="switch" aria-checked="false" x-ref="switch" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled"
      :class="{ 'bg-primary-600': on, 'bg-gray-200': !(on) }" aria-labelledby="availability-label"
      aria-describedby="availability-description" :aria-checked="on.toString()" @click="on = !on">
      <span aria-hidden="true"
        class="pointer-events-none inline-block h-5 w-5 transform rounded-full bg-white shadow ring-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out translate-x-0"
        x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }"></span>
    </button>
    <input type="checkbox" style="display:none" name="free_books" x-model="on">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. Do you have any error message in the browser's console?

Comment: You are right it works fine